# Compiling a C++ Project with Cygwin

Tags: c++, compilation, cygwin

I've made a little project to get experience with OOP in C++, i'm on Windows (with Cygwin).
The classes are `point.h` (the base class), `point.cpp` (implementation of `point.h`), `coloredPoint.h` (the derivated class), `coloredPoint.cpp` (implementation of the derivated class) and `main.cpp` (whic creates a point object and a `coloredPoint` object).
To run the main I type

`g++ point.cpp coloredPoint.cpp main.cpp -o main`

and all goes well! I know that this may could sound stupid...but is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C++ you will want to replace gcc with g++ or add -lstdc++ (if you want to use the std c++ library) to your gcc command line:

gcc point.cpp coloredPoint.cpp main.cpp -o main -lstdc++

or

g++ point.cpp coloredPoint.cpp main.cpp -o main

which links the std c++ library with your compiled code. With g++ you do not have to add this step.

Comment: I've made a mistake, i actually use g++ and not gcc! So i usually write "g++ point.cpp coloredPoint.cpp main.cpp" and all go well...is still the right way?

Comment: Yes, see my answer above to understand the difference.

Comment: @user2941936 Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you've realised you've made a mistake in your question, please edit the question to reflect the correction so that the question is clear for future readers - don't just mention it on a comment to an answer. I've edited it for you.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my bad english, i'll keep it in mind!